# Is it possible to change the error class name on jQuery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to change the class that jQuery Validate applies to inputs that have an error

Change this

```
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" value="" maxlength="100"
class="error">
```

to this

```
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" value="" maxlength="100" 
class="customErrorClass">
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try specifying the `errorClass` property:

```
$('.selector').validate({
    errorClass: 'customErrorClass',
    rules: { ... },
    messages: { ... }
});
```

Comment: Works like a champ, thanks. That is NOT on [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) page.

Comment: @guanome, no, but it is on [this one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).

Comment: The old documentation links above no longer work. Here is an updated link for 2021: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorclass

Answer (score 0):

The one can use code as following for Custom Css

```
<style>
  .myErrorCssClass {
    border: solid 1px #ff0000;
  }
</style>

<script>
  $('#form1').validate({
    errorClass: "myErrorCssClass",
    rules: {
      Name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 10
      },
      LastName: {
        required: true
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```